# How can I access messages inside an ios app built using react native?

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, react-native

I want to log transaction messages in a ios app (built using react native) like the microsoft sms organizer does in android. Is it possible to read the message irrespective of the language the app is built in or ios just does not allow it

Answer (score 0):

iOS does not allow you to access these messages. As you suspect, it's completely unrelated to what technology or language you use. See the [Messages](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages) and [MessageUI](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messageui) frameworks for what is permitted, but it's extremely limited, and focused on building extensions inside of Messages, and accessing the Messages UI inside your app, not apps that can replace Messages.

You may also want to look at [SMS and Call Reporting](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/sms_and_call_reporting) to see if it's helpful for your purposes. But iOS is not going to give you all the messages and let you build your own app to manage them.

Comment: I want to fetch all the transaction messages only into my app and show them, can I do that?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "transaction messages," but if you mean "SMS and iMessages," no. If you mean information about the messages (like who they were sent to and when, without the contents), the answer is also no. I'm not sure what else you would mean.